# I want to integrate these two angularJS Dependency Injection in one project

Tags: angularjs, electron, videogular

I'm working on a project where I need to integrate a video plugin named "videogular" on angular-filemanager using electronJS platform .

this is the link for the [videogular](http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/how-to-start/)

this is my project Dependency Injection :

```
(function (angular) {
        'use strict';
        var FileManagerApp = angular.module('FileManagerApp');

        FileManagerApp.controller('FileManagerCtrl',
            ['$scope', 
            '$rootScope', 
            '$window', 
            '$translate', 
            'fileManagerConfig', 
            'item', 'fileNavigator', 
            'apiMiddleware',
        function ($scope,$rootScope, $window, $translate, fileManagerConfig, Item, FileNavigator, ApiMiddleware)
```

and this is the videogular Dependency Injection :

```
angular.module('myApp',
        [
            "ngSanitize",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"])
    .controller('HomeCtrl',
        ["$sce", function ($sce) {

        }]
    );
```

when I tried to integrate it this way :

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    var FileManagerApp = angular.module('FileManagerApp',
    [
        "ngSanitize",
        "com.2fdevs.videogular",
        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
        "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"]);

    FileManagerApp.controller('FileManagerCtrl',
     [
         '$scope', 
         '$sce', 
         '$rootScope', 
         '$window', 
         '$translate', 
         'fileManagerConfig', 
         'item', 
         'fileNavigator', 
         'apiMiddleware',

                function (
                        $scope ,
                        $sce,
                        $rootScope, 
                        $window, 
                        $translate, 
                        fileManagerConfig, 
                        Item, 
                        FileNavigator, 
                        ApiMiddleware) {
```

[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvxqn.png)

please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: any specific reason for using two angular module?

Comment: I don't want to use two angular modules , I just need to use one 
I need to use the videogular in my project , and I didn't know how

Comment: can u add `angular.js` rather than `angular.min.js` to have a better readable message and update the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `FileManagerApp` in `myApp` module to use it.

```
angular.module('myApp',
        [
            "ngSanitize",
            'FileManagerApp', // <--- here
            "com.2fdevs.videogular",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"])
```

or if vice-versa:

```
var FileManagerApp = angular.module('FileManagerApp',
[
    "ngSanitize",
    "myApp", // < -- here
    "com.2fdevs.videogular",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"]);
```

**Note**

Make sure you are not injecting

```
    "com.2fdevs.videogular",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"
```

to both of the modules.Just inject in either one.

Comment: can I do the reverse ?
integrate the the videogular with the file manager because I did a lot of work there

Comment: @Firas : Do you mean injecting `myApp` to `FileManagerApp` ??. Yes, you can do that. Just reverse the injection. its difficult to understand your actual question. Please update the error image as per my suggestion as well

Comment: all what I want is the make videogular work on my file manager

Comment: @Firas : Try the other part of my answer. And update ur question as per my feedback. You are ignoring that and asking for a solution.